# How to pass a TListstring by reference wrapped into a Class?

Tags: c++, parameters, reference

File .h:

```
class A{
    public:
    TStringList &tsl;
    A(TStringList &arg) : tsl(arg) {}
}
void foo(A& dto);
```

File cpp:

```
void foo(A& dto);
{
     dto.tsl.String[0] = "AAA";
}
```

Use:

```
     TStringList *a= new TStringList();
     ......(some code )......
     A dtoArg=A(*a);
     a.String[0]="BBB";
     foo(dtoArg); 
  Printf("first element now is %s",a.String[0] );
```

Even if the project compiles and all seems fine at runtime, the behavior is not the expected one. The output is `BBB` and not `AAA` as expected. This means that the `TStrngList` is passed by value and not by reference.

So, how to pass the `TString` list by reference. I won't copy the `TSringList` when it is passed to function `foo()`.

Comment: The code in this question does not look like it compiles (eg in the printf line the "a.String[0]" should probably be "a->String[0]", since 'a' is a pointer).  Can you provide an example that's complete and reproducible, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: The code is incomplete, make a compiling sample in a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your TStringList is defined, but when I replace it witha mock class like

```
struct TStringList {
    TStringList() { String.resize(10); }
    vector<string> String;
};
```

and correct your typos like `a.String[0]` to `a->String[0]`, then it works fine for me.

Whats the return type of `operator []` for the TStringList?
I believe the `......(some code )......` might be worth digging into?!
Please make sure you submit a complete and reproducible test case next time.

Comment: you can think a TStringList as a vector of string. TstringList is not a custo object it comes with some library of borland6 C++. It no matter what it is.  Ithink the point is general.  How to pass an object  by reference if i have its pointer available?-  Usually we have : foo(type & arg) as declaration and having type x  we can pass by reference : foo(x). But here we have type *x= new type ();

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all,
all works fine. The error was in my unit test and not in the tested code.....
So, this topic can be closed or removed. The TStringList has no problem to be passed by reference.